# Reduce the size of Image in Splash Screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a image which is quite big for Splash Screen. I want to reduce the size of this image but unable to do so. I have read already answers to this question which are here on SO but none of those answers helped. Please help.

**launch_background.xml**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="?android:colorBackground" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/bluetoothicon"
            android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Splash Screen**

[Splash Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SnCy.jpg)

**Bluetooth Image**

[bluetooth-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEPpo.png)

Comment: Did you tried changes of `height` and width` in the above xml?

Comment: Yes, you can see it in the code itself.

Comment: Attach ss of your splash screen and `bluetoothicon` so i can try.

Comment: @DholaHardik Updated Post. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="?android:colorBackground" />

    <item
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="200dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/bluetoothicon" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**Output**
[image: splash]